# Python Draw grid Function

Tags: python, python-2.7

Please i have been finding it a little difficult to draw a grid like this..

i need some help to  have a specific functon that can draw me any given grid of numbers given

```
def grid(f, l):
print("{:10}".format("---+---" * f))
print("|{:12}|".format(" " * l))
print("|{:12}|".format(" " * l))
print("|{:12}|".format(" " * l))
print("{:10}".format("---+---" * f))
```

Comment: What output are you expecting here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that ?

```
def grid(row, col):
  """version with string concatenation"""
  sep = '\n' + '+---'*col + '+\n'
  return sep + ('|   '*col + '|' + sep)*row

print(grid(3,7))
```

Result:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Although it may be more efficient to use list comprehension combined with `join`

Answer (score 0):

```
def grid(row, col):
    x = ('+----' * col + '+')
    y = ('\n' +'|    ' *  (col+1)) 
    return ((x + 4*y) +'\n')*row + x
print(grid(3,2))

Result :
+----+----+
|    |    |
|    |    |
|    |    |
|    |    |
+----+----+
|    |    |
|    |    |
|    |    |
|    |    |
+----+----+
|    |    |
|    |    |
|    |    |
|    |    |
+----+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n=11
a=('+')*1 + (int(n/2)-1)*'-' + ('+')*1 + (int(n/2)-1)*'-' + ('+')*1
print(a)
for i in range(0,4):
    b=('|')*1 + (int(n/2)-1)*' ' + ('|')*1 + (int(n/2)-1)*' ' + ('|')*1
    print(b)
print(a)
for i in range(0,4):
    b=('|')*1 + (int(n/2)-1)*' ' + ('|')*1 + (int(n/2)-1)*' ' + ('|')*1
    print(b)    
print(a)
```